# Learning php - How to query the database from logged_in.php?

Tags: php, pdo, this

Im trying to learn php and have set up a login system using php-login.net (advanced script). The script uses an index.php file to check if the user is logged in (via login.php)

Within login.php, the script uses a function "databaseConnection" to connect to the database as

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

An example query is executed as:

```
$query = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE users SET username = :user_name  WHERE user_id = 1');
$query ->bindValue(':user_name  ', $user_name  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query ->execute();
if ($query_update->rowCount() == 0) {
    // Something here
} else {
    // Something else here
}
```

index.php checks if the user is logged in and if logged in, loads logged_in.php

**My question is:** How do I select something from the database within logged_in.php. Should i create a new db connection? If so how. I cannot reference $this->db_connection->prepare within logged_in.php

Also, what's a good source to learn step by step. I tried http://php.net/manual/ but that isnt making sense to me.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what "loads" mean.

Comment: I would suggest http://w3schools.com

To get data from database read about select queries

Answer (score -1):

use php frameworks. so that it is fast and easy. Here login controller ive used in codeigniter framework

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');



class Login extends CI_Controller {



    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();  

        $this->load->model('login_model', 'lm');

        $this->load->model('posts_model', 'pm');

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Hong_Kong');

    }



  //check password in the database

  public function check_database($password){

   $username = $this->input->post('username');

    $result = $this->lm->login($username, $password);

    if($result){

      $sess_array = array();

      foreach($result as $row){

        $sess_array = array(

                      'id'=>$row->user_id,

                      'username'=>$row->username,                      

                      );

        $this->session->set_userdata('loggedIn', $sess_array);

      }

      return true;

    }else{

      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid Username or Password.');

      return false;

    }

  }



    public function auth(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

            $this->index();

        }else{

            redirect('post');

        }



    }



    public function index(){

        $data['title'] = "Login here | OkDito.ph Cebu's # 1 Buy and Sell Website";

        $data['great_deals'] = $this->pm->greatdeals();//get all items



        $data['getAllPendingPosts'] = $this->pm->getAllPendingPosts();

        $tmp_pending = array();

        $tmp_pending = $data['getAllPendingPosts'];

        if(!empty($tmp_pending )){

            $pending = 1;

        }

        else{

            $pending = 0;

        }



        $data['pending'] = $pending;



        if($this->session->userdata('loggedIn')){

            $login = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');

            if(!empty($login)){

                redirect('post');

            }

        }

        else{

            $this->template_lib->set_view('index_view', 'login_view', $data,'',$data);

        }

    }





}
```

model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*

 * User library for the Model..all commonly used functions should be placed here

 * @author: team gabayan

 * @created: 7/1/11

 */

class Login_model extends CI_Model{



    //check if email exist in the database

    public function email($email){

        $this->db->select(

                'tbl_users.email'

                )

                ->from('tbl_users')

                ->where('email', $email);

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q->num_rows() == 1){

            return $q->result();

        }else{

            return false;

        }

    }
```

Here. Hope this helps

```
  public function login($username, $password){

     $sha_password = sha1($password);

     $this->db->select(

                'tbl_users.user_id,

                 tbl_users.username,

                 tbl_users.password,

                 tbl_users.status

                '

                )

              ->from('tbl_users')

              ->where('tbl_users.username', $username)

              ->where('tbl_users.password', $sha_password);

      $query = $this->db->get();

      if($query->num_rows() == 1){

        return $query->result();

      }else{

        return false;

      }

  }
```

}//endclass

/*End of File Login_model.php*/

/*File Location: ./application/models/login_model.php*/

Comment: Your login form is not secure. Using `sha` on passwords is highly discouraged as `sha` is too fast. You should be using [bcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) like so, `$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`.